# inserting multiple checkedlistbox values in one single row database using c#

Tags: c#, postgresql, checkedlistbox

I'm making a windows form where in all the checkedlist values are stored in one row. However it only stores one value.

Question is, is it possible to store all the checkedlist values in a single row in which only their assigned ids are stored?

This is my previous code below. if you find any mistakes or if you have any idea on how to edit to make it work, it would be a big help for me. Thanks!

```
foreach (DataRowView item in this.checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Insert into name(eid, name, famid) Values (@eid, @name, @famid)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
    string value = item.Row[0].ToString().Split(',');
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@famcon", value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I think this code won't _even_ compile since `Split(',')` returns `string[]` not `string`. What are you try to do exactly? You wanna insert all splited strings in different rows for `@famcon` parameter?

Comment: @SonerGönül what i wanted is to insert in one cell/row in table all the checkedlistbox values because it only stores one value. i thought Split(',') would do. I guess Im wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C#, use this code but gotta change the default name to yours.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string Str = "";
            if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (Str == "")
                    {
                        Str = checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                        label1.Text = Str;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Str += ", " + checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString();
                        label1.Text = Str;
                    }
                }
                // Make your connection to the DataBase and insertion code starting within that area.
                MessageBox.Show("Your selection is for :" + Str);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select one name at least to work it out!");
            }
            while (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count > 0)
            {
                checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.CheckedIndices[0],false);
            }
                        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```